# Bouncing object using Vector3.Reflect as Quaternion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

So I'm having this problem where I am trying to make bullets ricochet off obstacles in Unity. Currently I am using Vector3.Reflect to set Vector3.Forward of my object.

[Expected Result vs. Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64821.png)

My expected result would be that the bullet follows the red lines. Each of the objects it is bouncing off are rotated by 45 degrees so the bullet should follow a perfect 90 degree bounce. But what is actually happening is on the second bounce the bullet follows the blue line and from the point gets stuck in the corner.

```
public int bulletSpeed;
Rigidbody bulletRigidBody;

void Start()
{
    //Get bullet rigidbody
    if (bulletRigidBody == null)
    {
        bulletRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    bulletRigidBody.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Wall")
    {
        //change forward vector based on reflection against object
        transform.forward = Vector3.Reflect(collision.contacts[0].point, collision.contacts[0].normal);

        //add velocity to bullet based on new forward vector
        bulletRigidBody.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;
    }

}
```

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTfYN.png)

Im assuming my problem is either something to do with returning the incorrect normal or because I am setting the Forward vector instead of rotating but I am unsure of how to convert Vector3.Reflect into something a Quaternion can understand

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to add your answer, but add your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I have been working on this problem for 2 days but as soon as I post the question I figure it out

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //if (collision.collider.tag == "Wall")

        //Store new direction
        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.Reflect(transform.forward, collision.contacts[0].normal);
        //Rotate bullet to new direction
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);

        //add velocity to bullet based on new forward vector
        bulletRigidBody.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;


}
```